# Purpose of this dash character in Regex capture

Tags: regex

I am trying to understand the purpose of `-` in this regex capture clause

```
(?P<slug>[\w-]+)
```

This is what I came up for when search for a dash

> A dash (-) can be used to specify a range. So the dash is a
>   metacharacter, but only within a character class.If you want to use a
>   literal dash within a character class, you should escape it with a
>   backslash, except when the dash is the first or last character of the
>   character class. So, the regexp [a-z] is equal to [az-] and [-az],
>   they will match any of those three characters.

My questions is what is the `-` after \w

Comment: "So, the regexp [a-z] is equal to [az-] and [-az], they will match any of those three characters." - that sounds wrong. `[a-z]` would match the _range_ lowercase a through characters till lowercase z. Whereas the other two are functionally equivalent, they will only match one of three characters, the `z`, the `a` and the `-`. Mouse over https://regexr.com/3oe5o for clarification, and to play with the regex in regexr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at what my former CS professor would refer to as a rabbit (out of a hat):

```
(?P<slug>[\w-]+)
```

The reason it is a rabbit is because normally your research is correct and dash is used as a part of a range of characters.  But in this case, the dash is a *literal* dash, since it appears at the end of the character class.

So here `[\w-]+` means to match one or more word characters *or* literal dashes.

If you want to include a literal dash in a character class, a safer way is to escape it:

```
[\w\-]+
```

Then, the dash may be placed anywhere in the class.

Comment: Not true: *The regex engine would first try to find a range, that failing, would treat the dash as a literal character.*. A dash first or last is a literal, always; when in those positions it never "tries to find a range".

Comment: @Bohemian I used that language with the intention of showing that using an unescaped dash always leaves an ambiguity as to its intention.